# Question re: Installing New Power Strip in Kitchen

Tags: electrical, kitchens, receptacle

In my apartment's kitchen, I have a wall outlet on the wall on one side of the sink, but I'd like to add several more outlets on the other wall, on the other side of the sink.

I don't own this apartment, so it's not like I can start adding more wall outlets, but I'm wondering if there's some way I can add a nice looking GFCI power strip and run the cord along the wall, plugged into the existing wall outlet.

Anyone know the details of how and if this could be done? The only GFCI power strips that I've seen are big, ugly, and industrial. I'm looking for something a little nicer and cleaner (similar to what a normal power strip looks like- but I can't use that since it's near the sink).

Answer (score 3):

You can plug a normal power bar into a GFCI outlet and get the same protection as plugging directly into the GFCI.

If the outlet you'd be plugging into isn't a GFCI, you might negotiate with your landlord to get one.

Or get something like this:

[https://www.amazon.com/TRC-90265-6-012-Shockshield-Portable-Protection/dp/B000XVG72G?th=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000XVG72G)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wire mold makes thin plug strips that come in all kinds of configurations [like this example](http://www.securitystoreusa.com/wiremold-bk20gb506-black-plugmold-multi-outlet-power-strip-5-ft-10-outlet-p-9360?gclid=CKaU0eW6g9ACFRBEfgodvCkK7A). They are expensive but I have had them on my big repair bench for over 20 years with daily usage and they still worked well when I retired from that position.